# Violation of unique key constraint while inserting row using EF 4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

My object which I am going to insert has a parent object as a navigational property.

When I "add" the object to insert it, it also set the `ObjectStateManager` of my parent object (which is already inserted) to `Added` and try to insert it. I've verified it in SQL Profiler and thus raises the exception of unique key violation.

I am getting rid of this in two ways

1. Before adding the object I set all the navigational properties to null
2. Set the `ObjectStateManager` of parent object to `Modified`.

But this seems more like hack than a solution. I believe Entity Framework must have some elegant solution to this.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is correct solution for this problem. When you call `AddObject` EF will attach all entities from the object graph in `Added` state. If you also have existing entities in the graph you must tell EF about them by either setting their state to `Unchanged` or `Modified`.

Comment: Is there any easy way(single step) to set modified/unchanged state to all the existing entities. Rather than doing it one by one for aLL navigational properties..

Comment: No but you can use inverse operation by Attaching whole graph and changing added entities to Added state but it can cause some issues with added relations.